# Getting the minimum value in a row and the cell above it

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

So I have a file of the form above. The hyperlinks you see in row 2 are suppliers. Under each supplier there is the cost for the EAN in that row (EAN is in column A). I am trying to return in column B the minimum price + the supplier that is offering that. How can I do this?

So far I have just done min(rowX) to get the minimum price (as you can see in column B), next I imagine I can use ampersand to concatenate this to the supplier in question but not sure how to use "offset" (or otherwise) to get the supplier? For example, in column B, the first entry should become:

"11.77 - FennixBrokers"

This is in reference to the fact that the minimum price offered by any supplier for this EAN is 11.77 and in this case that happens to be an offer from FennixBrokers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=BYROW(C3:Z,LAMBDA(z,IF(COUNTA(z)=0,,MIN(z)&" - "&FILTER(C2:Z2,z=MIN(z)))))
```

- 

[image]